Line integral squeeze theorem counterexample
Problem
In the second type of line integrals, generally, there are no properties related to the order of integration as in the case of the "standard" integral. Provide a concrete counterexample (with proof) using a piecewise smooth curve ( AB ) and continuous functions $f$, $g$, and $h$ defined on this curve, such that the following statement does not hold:
$
\text{If } f(x, y) \leq g(x, y) \leq h(x, y) \quad \forall (x, y) \in AB,
$
and
$
\int_{AB} f(x, y) \, dx = \int_{AB} h(x, y) \, dx = c,
$
then also
$
\int_{AB} g(x, y) \, dx = c.
$
Proof Outline
Let $AB$ be the curve parametrized as $ r(t) = (t, t^2) $ for $t \in [0, 1]$, so that $ x(t) = t $ and $ y(t) = t^2 $. It is clear that these functions have continuous derivatives on the interval $ [0, 1] $, and
$
x'(t)^2 + y'(t)^2 = 1 + 2t \neq 0 \quad \forall t \in [0, 1]$
so the curve is smooth, and all smooth curves are piecewise smooth. Now, we need to construct $ f(x, y) $, $ g(x, y) $, and $ h(x, y) $ that satisfy the given inequality $ f(x, y) \leq g(x, y) \leq h(x, y) $, and ensure that the integrals of $ f(x, y)=c $ and $ h(x, y) =c$, but the integral of $g(x, y) \neq c $.

My Problem
I, for the life of me can't think of any good counterexamples to use for this proof. I know that there exist plenty, but i just can't think of any that meet the set of criteria. Maybe i'm using a bad curve for $AB$. Any help?

@Ted What do you mean by this?

I guess Ted Shifrin means a curve whose initial point is at some point $P$ and whose end point $Q$ is to the left of $P$.

I'm quite new to curves, how would one go about constucting one of these.

$\gamma:[0,1] \to \Bbb R^2$ given by $\gamma(t) = (-t,0)$, for example. $\gamma(0) = (0,0)$ and $\gamma(1) = (-1,0)$ is to the left of $(0,0)$.

Okay, so for example, i could change my curve to be $r(t)=(-t^2,-t)$ and that should work? How does this help me in terms of thinking of a counterexample?

Why would you choose that instead of $r(t) = (-t,0)$, which is simpler?

How does that help you to get a counterexample? Try some some functions $f, g, h$ and see what you get when calculate the integrals...

You are correct $(-t, 0)$ is simpler. However what ever i integrate i cant get the integrals of $f$ and $h$ to equal. I get the necessary inequalities down, but the integrals never equal. What am I missing, should i try sin and cosine functions or what?

Yes, I removed my suggestion because I realized that it doesn't seem to help. I was wanting the inequality to reverse. That is, if $f(x,y)\le g(x,y)$ and the curve goes from right to left then $\int_C f(x,y),dx \ge \int_C g(x,y),dx$. But with the squeeze there, I am not convinced that the statement is false. (The beginning of the paragraph talks about what I just said, however.) Where did this come from?

It's part of my multivariable analysis homework. I got stuck on this problem. Do you think there is an error in the original statement, so that it is actually true?

Here's a new hint: Pick a curve $AB$ so that $A$ and $B$ have the same $x$-coordinate, take $f(x,y)=-1$, $h(x,y)=1$. Can you make $g(x,y)$ so that the integral of $g(x,y)$ will not be $0$?

So for example $r(t)=(0,t)$ $t\in[0;1]$. $f(x,y)=-1$ and $h(x,y)=1$. If $g(x,y)=t$, then our inequalities should be in check. And the integral of $g$ should be $\frac{1}{2}$? Although I dont think the integrals of $f$ and $h$ are equal in this case?

First, you need $g$ to be a function of $x,y$. Second, you need to follow my suggestion carefully. Reread it. Draw some pictures.

Is the curve i proposed something that could work? What if $g(x,y)=x+y$ for example the integral wouldn't be zero then. And I don't understand how the integrals of $f$ and $h$ would be equal still.

Guessing randomly is not the way to do mathematics. Why did I pick $-1$ and $1$ for the functions?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
